# How do you evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(\sin x) dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do you evaluate the integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(\sin x)\ dx\ \text{?}$$

Comment: do you want to know this integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi{2}}\log(\sin(x))dx$$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your own thoughts on the problem.  What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes please answer

Comment: i think this integral was always solved in this forum

Comment: I simply integrated log sin x DX as 1/sinx and put limits

Comment: @Animesh, why did you do that? $\log(\sin x) \ne \frac{1}{\sin x}$

Comment: Please post your and.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: notice we have $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(\sin x)\ dx\tag 1$$
Using property of definite integral, we get
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) \right)\ dx$$ $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(\cos x\right)\ dx\tag 2$$ 
Adding (1) & (2), we get $$I+I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(\sin x\cos x\right)\ dx$$
$$2I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{2}\right)\ dx$$
$$2I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(\sin 2x\right)\ dx-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(2)\ dx$$
Hopefully, You can solve further

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Show that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(x))dx.$$

Then
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(x))dx\right)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}\right)dx\underset{u=2x}{=}\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin(u))du-\frac{\pi\ln 2}{4}=...$$